react-scripts fail by docker
I get this message on terminal when docker-compose up -d --build
➜  InvoiceApp git:(main) ✗ docker-compose logs frontend
invoice_v2_react  | yarn run v1.22.19
invoice_v2_react  | $ react-scripts start
invoice_v2_react  | /bin/sh: react-scripts: not found
invoice_v2_react  | error Command failed with exit code 127.
invoice_v2_react  | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I thought my configuration is perfect
FROM node:20-alpine

# Ustaw katalog roboczy w kontenerze
WORKDIR /appreact

# Skopiuj plik package.json i yarn.lock (jeśli istnieje)
COPY ./appreact/package.json ./
COPY ./appreact/yarn.lock ./
# Zainstaluj zależności projektu
RUN yarn install

# Skopiuj pozostałe pliki projektu do katalogu roboczego
COPY ./appreact .
RUN yarn build

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Uruchom serwer deweloperski za pomocą react-scripts
CMD ["yarn", "start"]

I tried many configuration, it actually work, but looks ugly, we=hen I added globally in this file
yarn add globally react-scripts


do you have any suggestions?

Is react-scripts included in your package.json file?  How are you running the container; are you using Docker volumes or bind mounts to hide the image content?

@DavidMaze yes, I have included react-scripts in package.json. I have volumes   volumes:       - ./appreact:/appreact

That volumes: block can cause problems like what you're describing, since the results of the RUN yarn install and RUN yarn build commands are completely hidden by the bind mount.  Does deleting it help at all?
